# Overloading assignment operator with same code for multiple signatures?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, dry

Say I have a class C:

```
class C {
    int m_i { 0 };
};
```

Now this class can be used for non-volatile and volatile objects:

```
C x;
volatile C y;
```

I want to be able to assign volatile to non-volatile, non-volatile to volatile and non-volatile to non-volatile. So I overload C's assignment operator:

```
class C {
    int m_i { 0 };
public:
    void operator=(const volatile C& source) volatile {
        m_i = source.m_i;
    }

    void operator=(const C& source) {
        m_i = source.m_i;
    }
};
```

Can this be done in a DRY way, without repeating the code in the `operator=` functions?

Comment: I have to ask, do you really need this?  Normally classes are not volatile as volatile is for mapping to memory that can change for outside the programs scope.  Normally you juts need `const` and non-const.

Comment: and `= default;` should do the job.

Comment: My use case is the following: I have a similar class for the purpose of storing data originating from an ISR (Interrupt Service Routine) in Arduino code. In the ISR, I populate an instance which is accessed only from the ISR. When the instance is "finished"/"completed", it is assigned to the next free instance of same type in a circular buffer structure. This structure is accessed from the ISR und from the "main" loop, so it is declared volatile (non-volatile to volatile assignment). When data is popped off the buffer, it is the other way round. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Jarod42 how would I use `= default;` with `void operator=(const volatile C& source) volatile`?

Comment: Indeed, it seems `volatile` doesn't have default :-/

Answer (score 0):

So after thinking about it for a while, this is the best solution I could come up with:

```
class C {
    int m_i { 0 };

    void assignFrom(const volatile C& src, const bool volatileSrc = true, const bool volatileSelf = true) volatile {
        auto& nqSrc = volatileSrc ? src : const_cast<const C&>(src);
        auto& self = volatileSelf ? *this : *const_cast<C*>(this);
        self.m_i = nqSrc.m_i;
    }

public:
    void operator=(const C& src) volatile {
        // non-volatile to volatile assignment
        assignFrom(src, false);
    }

    C& operator=(const volatile C& src) {
        // volatile to non-volatile assignment
        assignFrom(src, true, false);
        return *this;
    }

    C& operator=(const C& src) {
        // non-volatile to non-volatile assignment
        assignFrom(src, false, false);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I tested it and it seems to be working fine.